# Why can't we directly assign arr to pointer to array

Tags: c++, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

I have an array of 5 integers.
arr and &arr is same address.
So why number 2 gives compilation error and and 3 works fine.

```
  int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  1. int *p = arr;
  2. int (*p1)[5] = arr //Compilation Error
  3. int (*p1)[5] = &arr; //Works fine.
  
     arr = 0x61fdf0 and &arr= 0x61fdf0
```

Comment: `arr` decays to `int*`. `&arr` is of type `int (*)[5]`. So the typechecking does well.

Comment: `arr` and `&arr` are the same address, but are not the same types.

Comment: Can you please explain how does this differ in C and C++ ?? In my opinion this will be same in c and c++

Comment: no error in C, thats a difference: https://godbolt.org/z/hf5PKK

Comment: its just that c gives warning.and c++ error..so both interpret this to be wrong,  so i think the tags are not wrong,  Any person knowing c ,c++ can explain it ..so no base for spam of language tags ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the initialized object and the initializer have different pointer types and there is no implicit conversion from one pointer type to another.

In this declaration

```
int (*p1)[5] = arr;
```

the initialized object has the type `int ( * )[5]` while the initializer has the type `int *` due to the implicit conversion of the array designator to a pointer to its first element.

You have to write

```
int (*p1)[5] = &arr
```

Or for example

```
int ( *p1 )[5] = reinterpret_cast<int ( * )[5]>( arr );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};   
    
    int ( *p1 )[5] = reinterpret_cast<int ( * )[5]>( arr );

    std::cout << "sizeof( *p1 ) = " << sizeof( *p1 ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( *p1 ) = 20
```

Objects can have equal values but different types.

Consider an another case.

Let's assume that you have an object of a structure type

```
struct A
{
    int x;
} a;
```

in this case  `&a` and `&a.x` have the same values but the types of the expressions are different. You may not write for example

```
int *p = &a;
```

the compiler will issue an error. But you can write

```
int *p = ( int * )&a;
```

or

```
int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>( &a );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    struct A
    {
        int x;
    } a = { 10 };
    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( ( void * )&a.x == ( void * )&a ) << '\n';
    
    int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>( &a );
    
    std::cout << "*p = " << *p << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
*p = 10
```

As for your one more question in a comment

> Can you decode this in simple language to understand int** p = new
> int*[5];

then in this expression with the operator new

```
new int*[5]
```

there is allocated memory for an array with 5 elements of the type `int *`. The expression returns a pointer to the first element of the array. A pointer to an object of the type `int *` (the type of elements of the allocated array) will have the type `int **`.

Comment: Can you decode this in simple language to understand
int** p = new int*[5];

Comment: Okay.Can you please share your views on this also ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66461618/why-cant-we-directly-assign-address-of-a-2d-array-to-pointer

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, it's for the same reason that this throws a compilation error:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *p = x;
}
```

When you have a pointer designated for an object type, you're supposed to assign the address of an object of that type. That being said, while the code above doesn't make sense, the code below does:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *p = &x;
}
```

This applies to arrays in the same way it applies to anything else.

```
int main()
{
    int x[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int (*p)[5] = x; // Compilation error.
    int (*p)[5] = &x; // Does exactly what it should.
}
```

You are correct in stating that `x` and `&x` might very well have the same value, so assigning `x` to the pointer instead of `&x` should work and make sense. While it does make sense from a technical perspective, it doesn't make sense from a semantic perspective. The c++ language prioritizes semantics to help the programmer avoid mistakes. Here's an example:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0x72fe1c; // Let's imagine that 0x72fe1c just so happens to be the address of x.
    // x is an int variable holding a value which just so happens to be equal to its address.
    int *p = x; // This is never desirable; thank the compiler for telling you something is wrong.
}
```

The above code makes sense from a technical perspective. `x` holds a value that happens to be equal to its own memory address, so what's the harm in assigning its value to a pointer? The "harm" lies in the fact that a c++ programmer would never want this in a practical situation because c++ is one level above assembly; you're not supposed to work with memory addresses like that. As such, the compiler forbids you from executing such code to help you avoid mistakes.