# Why can't we directly assign the address of a 2D array to a pointer?

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

Why can't we directly assign the address of a 2D array to a pointer?

Is there any way we can assign it in a single line, not with the help of a `for` loop?

Is there any other better approach?

```cpp
// Array of 5 pointers to an array of 4 ints 

int (*Aop[5])[4];

for(int i = 0;i<5;i++) 
{
    Aop[i] = &arr2[i];  //Works fine
} 
 
//Why this doesn't work int 
int (*Aop[5])[4] = &arr2[5][4]
```

Comment: Array initializers have to be literals, you can't assign arrays to each other.

Comment: What does `int (*Aop[5])[4];` mean here? Your intent isn't clear. Pointers to arrays of "fixed" sizes are somewhat useless because there's no bounds checking anyway.

Comment: When asking questions like this please focus on one of C or C++. Their behaviour can differ significantly.

Comment: If you used `std::vector` you *could* just assign them, and you wouldn't have to worry about raw pointers and manual copying. Which is also why you shouldn't tag *both* C and C++ because if you are asking about C the answer is obviously different than in C++

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
int (*Aop[5])[4];
```

does not declare a pointer. It is a declaration of an array of 5 pointers to one-dimensional arrays of the the `int[4]`.

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. However you could initialize it in its declaration as for example

```
int (*Aop[5])[4] = { &arr2[0], &arr2[1], &arr2[2], &arr2[3], &arr2[4] };
```

or

```
int (*Aop[5])[4] = { arr2, arr2 + 1, arr2 + 2, arr2 + 3, arr2 + 4 };
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 5, N = 4 };
    
    int arr2[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2 },
        { 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4 },
        { 5, 5, 5, 5 }
    };
    
    int (*Aop[M])[N] = { arr2, arr2 + 1, arr2 + 2, arr2 + 3, arr2 + 4 };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", ( *Aop[i] )[j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5
```

If you need to declare a pointer to the array `arr2` then you should bear in mind that array designators are implicitly converted (with rare exceptions) to pointers to their first elements. The array `arr2` has elements of the type `int[4]`. So a pointer to an object of this type will have the type `int ( * )[4]`. So you can write

```
int (*Aop )[4] = arr2;
```

Here is another demonstrative program that uses pointers in for loops to output elements of the array `arr2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 5, N = 4 };
    
    int arr2[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2 },
        { 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4 },
        { 5, 5, 5, 5 }
    };
    
    int (*Aop )[N] = arr2;
    
    for ( int ( *p )[N] = Aop; p != Aop + M; ++p )
    {
        for ( int *q = *p; q != *p + N; ++q )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *q );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

These work just fine to declare a pointer to the entire array:

```
int (*Ap)[4] = arr2;

int (*Bp)[5][4] = &arr2;
```

The size of an array only appears in its declaration, and NOT when passing it around.  `arrs[5][4]` is an out-of-bounds array access (out of bounds by a whole row and a whole column, so you can't even use legally it as the past-the-end reference by avoiding lvalue-to-rvalue conversion)